# When integrating SQL Server Reporting Services with SharePoint, does SharePoint have to be installed on the database server that hosts SSRS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssrs

I am configuring SSRS (2008 R2) in SharePoint integrated mode to work with a SharePoint (2010) site that is on another server, do I also have to install SharePoint on the database server that is hosting SSRS?  I should note that the SharePoint databases are also on the database server that is hosting SSRS.

Comment: I think I answered my own question, you do have to have SharePoint installed on the SSRS server because it uses the SharePoint Object Model to serve the reports in integrated mode ('Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SharePoint and SSRS on the same machine.  This does not need to be the same machine which has the actual databases on it (in fact it usually will not be the same machine).

Comment: [Insert forehead slap here]
Of course!  I was thinking about htis backwards all along, I shouldn't be installing SSRS on the database server at all.  Thanks!